# sediment at the bottom of brew

Tags: beer, sediment

I have just bought a [Coopers DIY beer kit](http://makebeer.net/About-the-DIY-Beer-Kit) and have started my first ever brew. Ive notticed at the bottom of the fermenter there is a lot of sediment is this normal or have I done something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "brew" do you mean in the kettle, in the fermentor, or in the bottles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick Google on the name tells me that this is an add water, sugar and yeast kit, so I am guessing you are referring to sediment in the fermentation bucket. In that case, the sediment is a perfectly normal part of the process. The yeast, which is doing its job of producing your alcohol, is multiplying, flocculating (clumping together) and settling out.

When it comes to bottling, don't disturb the sediment, just leave it behind in the bucket. Enjoy your brew, before you know it you'll be doing another!

Comment: "A quick Google on the name tells me that this is an add water, sugar and yeast kit..."  They're pretty popular down under.  They call it "Kit & Kilo" brewing - as in "start with this kit and add a kilo of sugar."

Comment: Hi thanks for the help yes the sediment is in the fermentation bucket. It is also in the bottom of the tap but im hoping it will be pushed out when i open the tap should i drain some out before i start bottling. Thanks again.

Comment: Assuming that the outlet for the tap is above the sediment level, then yes, just let it run clear before running into bottles. Don't open the tap too quickly in case the 'rush' disturbs the sediment. If it is covering the tap outlet you'd be better off siphoning into bottles.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on re-using the bottles you might want to spray out the sediment after you poor the beer in the glass. This will get the gunk out of there before it hardens and save you some work later.

Answer (score 0):

Coopers is a nice brew - I used to drink it when I was in Melbourne. However, the tradition then was to roll the bottle to stir up the sediment and drink it. I could never taste the difference. However, I wouldn't advise that with your homebrew - it might taste a bit yeasty/bitter. Probably best to leave it in the bottom of your bottle!